# when does a mikve purify a person

Tags: halacha, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mikvah-ritual-bath

Does a mikve purify a person when he/she is totally inside the water or when he/she emerges from the water?

please source and also provide a reason for why it is so. it would seem to me that the first option is correct. we find for example that yom kipur purifies (atones) every second when a person is in it.

Comment: "we find for example that yom kipur purifies (atones) every second when a person is in it" where do we find this?

Answer (score 5):

The general opinion seems to be that only when leaving the *mikva* does one become *tahor* - see Kesef Mishna, Avos Hatumah 6:16 כסף משנה הל' שאר אבות הטומאה ספ"ו. See further in the Encyclopedia Talmudis under מקוה - column תט, footnote 93 for other sources.

I'm not immersed :-) in the topic now, so I can't venture reason.